# WebView setBackgroundColor not work in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, background-color, setbackground

I've try all suggestion that I've found but no one works for me.
This code not affect background color on webview in Android:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.getSettings();
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

How I can make works this simply function?

Comment: I've tried black, white and transparent. Now I'mt trying with transparent.

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: you can't set background color for webview,I mean this will not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change this

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

to this

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

because it working fine.

see my full code..

**xml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.softeng.abcd.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2"
   >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java code.

```
 WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings();
        webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

output :

[image]

Comment: @Luca Panteghini see my update answer. and if it not work then try to `clean` the project.

Comment: With blue, yellow or green works but with white or transparent doesn't work. Strange thing!!! Appears gray and not white in same cases.

Comment: @LucaPanteghini No all are work in the case of `white` you have set your `parent` background to some other `Color` and in the case of `transaparent` it also work but the Human can't see `transparent` color so it can not display us. Otherwise it also work.

Comment: @LucaPanteghini glad to help you.

Comment: This also only works for certain colours for me too. Red, green, blue, yellow, all fine. White, off-white, not working. Any idea on how to get it to work?